# How to change input parameter of report to "DD-MM-YY" by default it takes input as "d/M/y" i have to pass inout parameter for select query

Tags: jasper-reports

How to change input date parameter of report to "DD-MM-YY", By default it convert input as "d/M/y",

```
select * from table where start_date between '08-02-18' and '05-05-18'
```

But here I used hard coded values, please suggest how to declare parametes which give date format like "DD-MM-YY".

I tried expression like this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YY").format($P{datefrom})
```

Comment: Try new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format($P{datefrom})

Comment: when i try to declare parameter with this i'm getting error,   Where should i have to apply the above cast method

Comment: You should add a small code snippet of your _jrxml_.

Answer (score 0):

Use below expression and change the format pattern vice versa as as per your requirement.
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format((new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy")).parse($P{parameter1}))

Comment: What is it? How to use this expression?

Comment: @Tech Whiz 
i'm new to ireport,where exactly i have to use the above expression